# How to open Battlefront2 from a desktrop shortcut?

Tags: origin, epic-games-launcher, star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

I got Battlefront 2 for free with the Epic Giveaway.

But to open it, both Origin **AND** Epic open up. Is there a way to open it with a desktop shortcut that does not open the Epic Launcher and/or the Origin software?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: You could launch the game from Origin instead. That way you won't need to launch the Epic Games Launcher (you'll still need Origin, though). That's how it works for Ubisoft and Rockstar games, though I can't check if the same is true for EA, since I can't even install Battlefront 2...

Comment: If you open it from Origin it also opens Epic @Nolonar